# Preventing Inno Setup from uninstalling empty directories created with createallsubdirs flag

Tags: inno-setup

I have a folder (database folder) that I would like to keep after uninstall (for saving users data and future reinstall), I have flagged top folder to never uninstall as well as all its files (and folders?) whether empty or not yet Inno Setup deletes these empty sub-folders (which I want to keep) during uninstall. Do I have to declare all the sub folders I want to keep or is their a flag I am missing?

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\db\data"; Flags: uninsneveruninstall; Permissions: everyone-full

[Files]
Source: "D:\sesam\db\data\*"; DestDir: "{app}\db\data"; Flags: recursesubdirs createallsubdirs uninsneveruninstall; Check: CheckNotExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\db\data'))
```

Before uninstall and after:

[image] [image]

As you can see it only keeps "non empty" folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me, consider reporting it.

---

Anyway, you can use the Inno Setup preprocessor to generate a list of `[Dirs]` entries for each subfolder:

```
[Dirs]
#define FindHandle
#define FindResult
#define SourceDataPath "D:\sesam\db\data"
#define TargetDataPath "{app}\db\data"

#sub ProcessFoundFile
  #define DirName FindGetFileName(FindHandle)
  #define DirPath SourceDataPath + "\" + DirName
  #if DirExists(DirPath) && (DirName != ".") && (DirName != "..")
    Name: "{#TargetDataPath + "\" + DirName}"; Flags: uninsneveruninstall
  #endif
#endsub

#for {FindHandle = FindResult = FindFirst(SourceDataPath + "\*", faDirectory); \
      FindResult; FindResult = FindNext(FindHandle)} ProcessFoundFile
#expr FindClose(FindHandle)
```

The above works for single-level only. If you need recursion, it's more complicated.

---

Put this at the end of your script to see and review, what the preprocessor generated:

```
#expr SaveToFile(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Preprocessed.iss")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that works great, although I need recursion, I will try to modify it to implement that. While technically I don't think its a bug, since the [FILES] section only marks "files" for keeping. Though it does create folders when using a wildcard. The question is should it be treating those created folders as files (and marking them) when using wildcard. If the latter is the intended effect, then yes its a bug else.. its a feature?